# Pyplot: change size of tick lines on axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider this reproducable example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21']
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3,figsize=(6, 3.5),dpi=300)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.025, hspace=0.2)
for ax in [a for b in axes for a in b]:
    ax.imshow(np.random.randint(2, size=(22,42)))
    ax.set_xticks([0,6,12,18,24,30,36,41])
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=3)
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
for ax in [item for sublist in axes for item in sublist][0::3]:
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(labels)))
    ax.set_yticklabels(labels,fontsize=3)
fig.savefig("example.png",bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: output png]

My issue is that even though I changed the tick font size, the lines of each tick remain the same.  This looks  ugly and wastes a lot of space, especially on the X axes. Any ideas how to get those lines smaller, thus that the xlabels are closer to the axis?

PS `tight_layout()` does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Make

`ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=3, length=2)`

and, right after,

`ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=3, length=2)`

This will make the ticks smaller, but won't get the labels any closer to the chart.

PS: `length=1` will make the ticks even smaller, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You could play with the `width` parameter:

`ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=3, width=0.1)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (line 4):

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3,figsize=(6, 3.5),dpi=300)
```

You can manipulate figsize. Example:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3,figsize=(3, 2),dpi=300).
```

Lets's compare both outputs:

[image]

The numbers on axes are bigger than old one.